# 'List index out of range error for strip()

Tags: python

I keep getting list index out of range error for following code while using 'strip()'

```
    duration = list(dataset['Duration'])
duration_hrs = []
dur = []
for i in range(len(duration)):
    duration[i].split(sep='h')
    duration[i].strip('m')
    dur.append(dur[i])
dur

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2384/3886452692.py in <module>
      6     duration[i].split(sep='h')
      7     duration[i].strip('m')
----> 8     dur.append(dur[i])
      9 dur

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Problem line is not strip(), it is dur.append(dur[I]), dur[I] causing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dur` is empty list `dur[i]` doesn't exist.

maybe you want this `dur.append(dur[i])` to change it to `dur.append(duration[i])`